# How come a UIViewController's view coordinate system starts after the navbar, but its height includes the navbar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I noticed that with a NavigationController on an iPhone, the height is 460. So it includes the whole screen except the status bar.

However, when I add something at coordinate 0, it shows up after the NavigationBar, although the size of the navigation bar is included in the height (meaning the entire frame of this view sticks off the screen).

Did I make a mistake? If not, why is it structured this way?

```
NSLog(@"Frame: %@", [NSValue valueWithCGRect: self.view.frame]); // prints {(0, 20), (320, 460)}
UIScrollView* scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.width, 50)];
[self.view addSubview: scrollView]; // showing up 44px *after* the nav bar
```

Comment: To get the frame You can use    `NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));`

Comment: @LithuT.V haha thanks much better when doing many logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already answered your other similar question, but here is one for this.

In `viewDidLoad` you will see the views height as 460 because at that point it hasn't resized to account for the Nav Bar.

But If you printed the same frame out in say `viewWillAppear` you will see that now the frames height has adjusted for the Nav Bar.

So if you want to add something in `viewDidLoad`, you need to add it based on the views frame, add whichever resizing mask will do the job you want, and see it adjust correctly once the view appears.

Comment: Haha yeah I was just about to close/self answer this one. Thanks again - and for anyone reading this, here's the link to the other question (about autoresizing masks, but has the same answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058038/