# Autoresizingmask instantly overrides initially set frame (creating a different and wrong layout)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to configure one of my views. I can set the dimensions properly, but when I add the autoresizing mask it instantly changes the size.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UIScrollView* scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height - 10)]; // -10 so I know it's not being hidden under the tabbar
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; // easy recognition
    scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self.view addSubview: scrollView];
    self.scroll = scrollView;
    UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(hmm)];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer: tap];

}

- (void) hmm {
    NSLog(@"Frame: %@", [NSValue valueWithCGRect: self.scroll.frame]);
}
```

I get 357 without the mask and 264 with the mask. There's a big white section between the scrollview and tabbar with the mask. Why is it like this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to account for the navigation and tabbar.

Try this. When you are initing the scrollview you are making it the size of the view before re size, and once it loads your view will automatically re size with the view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UIScrollView* scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height- 10)]; // -10 so I know it's not being hidden under the tabbar
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; // easy recognition
    scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self.view addSubview: scrollView];
    self.scroll = scrollView;
    UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(hmm)];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer: tap];

}
```

Comment: Woah, I didn't think of that. I guess it works normally because the tabbar and navbar are sorta "overlayed" on it. But when I do resizing I set it to the full height, and it automatically gets squished when I add the tabbar and navbar? Could you confirm this is what's happening (code does work, but I want to understand it all as to not encounter further errors)

Comment: Basically, the ViewControllers view is only given the space between the navigation bar and the tab bar. It is automatically squished to fit in that region after the view loads. When you set your scrollviews frame to that of the view in viewDidLoad, technically at that point in time it is too big. But since you set the resizing mask, it will automatically shrink the same amount the main view shrinks to fit in the visible area. That's the simplest way I think to think about it.